# Cannot access HttpApplicationState in Web API controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-2.0, asp.net-core-webapi, httpapplicationstate

I have a REST API application made with .NET Core 2.0.
I would like to access the `Application` property to store some global settings for all the application.

However, it doesn't seem to be available in any of my controllers

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

namespace EcommerceSynchronizer.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    public class ValuesController : Controller
    {
        // GET api/values
        [HttpGet]
        public string Get()
        {
            HttpContext.Current.Application["key"] = "value";
            return "aa";
        }
    }
}
```

Resharper complains that

`'HttpContext' does not contain a definition for 'Current' and no extension method 'Current' accepting a first argument ...`

I tried accessing with `HttpContext.Application` but it is not available either.

How can I access HttpApplicationState from a controller ?

Comment: Poor design and no longer available in asp.net core, check docs for suggested approach https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/app-state?view=aspnetcore-2.1&tabs=aspnetcore2x

Comment: Thanks, I had no idea this was removed. I will use Application State Data instead